# Declaring an object of a Windows API structure (DCB) - error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, serial-port, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a C++ program to communicate with a serial port device using Windows API in Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 7.

Trying to compile this bit of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;

DCB dcb;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get these errors pointing to `DCB dcb;`:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dcb'
```

[The DCB structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined in Winbase.h like this:

```
typedef struct _DCB {
    DWORD DCBlength;      /* sizeof(DCB)                     */
    DWORD BaudRate;       /* Baudrate at which running       */
    DWORD fBinary: 1;     /* Binary Mode (skip EOF check)    */
    DWORD fParity: 1;     /* Enable parity checking          */
    DWORD fOutxCtsFlow:1; /* CTS handshaking on output       */
    DWORD fOutxDsrFlow:1; /* DSR handshaking on output       */
    DWORD fDtrControl:2;  /* DTR Flow control                */
    DWORD fDsrSensitivity:1; /* DSR Sensitivity              */
    DWORD fTXContinueOnXoff: 1; /* Continue TX when Xoff sent */
    DWORD fOutX: 1;       /* Enable output X-ON/X-OFF        */
    DWORD fInX: 1;        /* Enable input X-ON/X-OFF         */
    DWORD fErrorChar: 1;  /* Enable Err Replacement          */
    DWORD fNull: 1;       /* Enable Null stripping           */
    DWORD fRtsControl:2;  /* Rts Flow control                */
    DWORD fAbortOnError:1; /* Abort all reads and writes on Error */
    DWORD fDummy2:17;     /* Reserved                        */
    WORD wReserved;       /* Not currently used              */
    WORD XonLim;          /* Transmit X-ON threshold         */
    WORD XoffLim;         /* Transmit X-OFF threshold        */
    BYTE ByteSize;        /* Number of bits/byte, 4-8        */
    BYTE Parity;          /* 0-4=None,Odd,Even,Mark,Space    */
    BYTE StopBits;        /* 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2               */
    char XonChar;         /* Tx and Rx X-ON character        */
    char XoffChar;        /* Tx and Rx X-OFF character       */
    char ErrorChar;       /* Error replacement char          */
    char EofChar;         /* End of Input character          */
    char EvtChar;         /* Received Event character        */
    WORD wReserved1;      /* Fill for now.                   */
} DCB, *LPDCB;`
```

Comment: Winbase.h != Windows.h

Comment: @stark: Not the problem, `windows.h` will include `winbase.h`

Comment: @stark: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214.aspx): *"Header: Winbase.h (**include Windows.h**)"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using precompiled headers, anything above the line

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

(or whatever the name of the header designated for precompilation)

gets ignored.

Try rearranging your includes to put that one first.

More explanation [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yu-use-precompiled-header-file), particularly important is this:

> The compiler treats all code occurring before the .h file as precompiled. It skips to just beyond the #include directive associated with the .h file, uses the code contained in the .pch file, and then compiles all code after filename.

Comment: Or put those other includes in `stdafx.h` which is kind of the point of precompiled headers.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes, putting system header includes inside `stdafx.h` is a good practice.  Definitely not recommended for project-local headers though, since doing so negates the whole advantage of PCH.